# NSHTTPCookie nil

Tags: ios, swift, nshttpcookie

here is my code

```
    let cookieProperties = [
        NSHTTPCookieOriginURL: Constants.baseUrl,
        NSHTTPCookiePath: "/",
        NSHTTPCookieName: "device_id",
        NSHTTPCookieValue: Constants.deviceId
    ]
    let cookiePropertiesVersion = [
        NSHTTPCookieOriginURL: Constants.baseUrl,
        NSHTTPCookiePath: "/",
        NSHTTPCookieName: "app_version_code",
        NSHTTPCookieValue: "50"
    ]

    let newCookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)
    let newCookieVersion = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookiePropertiesVersion)
    cookieStorage.setCookie(newCookie!)
    cookieStorage.setCookie(newCookieVersion!)
```

Error is at line

> cookieStorage.setCookie(newCookie!)

newCookie is nil and

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

error comes

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This may help you.
This happens due because `NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties)` is returns nil as `newCookie`, and you are trying to set `nil` in `cookieStorage`.

```
   if let newCookie = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookieProperties){
        cookieStorage.setCookie(newCookie!)
    }
    let newCookieVersion = NSHTTPCookie(properties: cookiePropertiesVersion)
```

Comment: No. Can't do that. I need the cookie to not be nil.

Comment: Are you sure that , you always get value of `newCookie` ?

Comment: Only when I open my app.

Comment: If you are 100% sure that you will get value of `newCookie` in each and every case, then you does not need to unwrap value and you can set it without checking value of `newCookie`, otherwise you have to use it. Thanks